# How do I go to street view in Google Earth Pro without using the pegman

Tags: google-earth

I put a place marker onto google earth but I want to be able to skip the step of having to put the pegman there in order to go to street view.
I'd like to be able to just double click my marker and then be taken into street view from there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unless you are talking about doing this programmatically this is probably the wrong Stack Exchange site to ask. There are probably more focused SE for _using_ Google Earth. If you are doing something programmatically then show us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving the desired view for your Placemark.

First create your placemark, then use the Pegman tool to fly in to StreetView and set your desired view (location, view direction, etc.).  Next, find your placemark in the list view (in the Places panel on the left), right-click the placemark, and select "Snapshot View".  Now, the current view is saved as the default view for the placemark.

You can test it by flying out of street view to some other location, then double-click your placemark (on the map or in the Places panel), and it should fly you directly back to your saved view in Street View.